# Is a matrix invertible/nilpotent whenever its determinant is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic

Let $A$ be a matrix having entries from a commutative ring. Then how can we prove that $A$ is invertible $\mod m$ for a positive integer $m$ if and only if $\det A$ is invertible $\mod m$?

Further if $A$ has entries from $\mathbb{Z}_m$, then can we also say that $A^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$ implies $\det A^n \equiv 0 \mod{m}$?

Comment: Cramer's rule ?

Comment: What do you mean by mod $m$ for an arbitrary commutative ring $R$? Do you mean in the ring $R/mR$?

Comment: @ Jose Brox Yes, sorry for not mentioning it. Take $R = \mathbb{Z}$ in particular.

Comment: @Jose Brox  One more question has been added. Please check.

Comment: Please, see the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED TO ANSWER THE NEW QUESTION**

Over any commutative ring $R$, the matrix $A\in$Mat$_n(R)$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A)$ is invertible in $R$:

a) If $A$ has inverse then $AA^{-1}=I_n$ implies $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$, so $\det(A)$ is invertible.

b) If $\det(A)$ is invertible, as there exists the adjoint matrix adj$(A)$, which satisfies
$$\text{adj}(A)A=\det(A)I_n,$$
we have that $\det(A)^{-1}$adj$(A)=A^{-1}$.

---

In addition, if $A^n=0$ then $\det(A^n)=(\det A)^n=0$, so if $A$ is nilpotent in Mat$_n(R)$ then $\det(A)$ is nilpotent in $R$, but not necessarily $0$ (unless there are no nontrivial nilpotents in $R$). The easiest example is a nilpotent element seen as a size-1 matrix (e.g., $2\in\mathbb{Z}_4$). More in general, if $m=p^k$, you can pick the diagonal $(k-1)\times(k-1)$ matrix $A$ with $p$ as diagonal entries, which has $A^k=0$ and $\det(A)=p^{k-1}\neq 0$, e.g.
$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
in $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: $Mat_n(R)$ means entries modulo $n$?

Comment: Means matrices of size $n\times n$ over the ring $R$.

Comment: A question: why accept the answer but not upvote it?

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot it. Hv done.